# Join Synology to Specific OU in Domain

Tags: active-directory, synology

I am trying to join my Synology server to my Active Directory domain.  I would like to limit it to a specific OU, for instance, with the following DN:

ou=corporate,dc=yeack,dc=local

However, I'm not quite sure how to fill out the information that it is asking for in the management interface, or if this is even possible.  Here is what it is asking for:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Synology specifically and the screenshot you posted doesn't appear to have a field to specify the target OU unless it's hidden in a sub-dialog on that "Domain Options" button.

But generally you have two options when you want a joined computer to live in a specific OU.

1. Join it to the default container and move it into the target OU afterwards. Generally speaking, computers don't care where they live in AD and moving them won't break them.
2. Pre-create the computer account in the target OU and then join it. The join should just take over the computer object you created assuming the user account you're using to join with has the appropriate permissions.